# After "du -a", video file format not supported in android

Tags: linux

I connected my android device to ubuntu, and ran the command `du -a . | sort -n -r | head -n 10` by going to the home directory of the android file system to know the top 10 largest folders occupying my disk space.

Now, after disconnecting the device, I went back to watch one of the videos I recorded from the camera and eventually found out that all the videos are now not playable because it says "File format isn't supported or files are corrupted".

I know I should have used some other tools for that purpose. But now how can I recover all these video files?

Comment: What was the current directory you executed the command in? Try to reboot the phone.

Comment: @Robert `Internal storage` was the current directory. Also, rebooting didn't help.

Comment: Cross-posted from [Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/684017/90391)

Comment: I would recommend to download the video files to the PC using `adb` and then analyze them if they are still valid video files. You should also mention the used device and Android version.

Comment: you did nothing wrong that must be some strange kind of coincidence